# Syntax error near the "INNER" keyword

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am building a Windows form app using a SQL server. The problem I am having is that I am getting an unhandled exception error when I call the .Fill function. Under additional info, it says that there is a syntax error near the `INNER` keyword. I have written the following code thus far:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Baseball\Baseball\Baseball.mdf';Integrated Security=True")
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet



    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim sql As String

        sql = "SELECT teammates.PlayerName, teammates.Number, teammates.BirthDate, Position.Position, teammates.Salary"
        sql += "From teammates INNER JOIN Position ON teammates.PositionID = Position.PositionID"



        With da
            .SelectCommand = New SqlCommand
            .SelectCommand.Connection = cn
            .SelectCommand.CommandText = sql
            .SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            cn.Open()
            .Fill(ds, "teammates")
            cn.Close()
        End With

        With grdPlayers
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
            .DataSource = ds
            .DataMember = "teammates"

        End With

        Call FormatGrid()



        cn = Nothing
        da = Nothing

    End Sub

    Private Sub FormatGrid()
        Dim rightStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle
        rightStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight

        Dim altStyles As New DataGridViewCellStyle
        altStyles.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
        grdPlayers.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = altStyles

        Dim curStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle
        curStyle.Format = "c"
        curStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight

        With grdPlayers
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Name"
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Number"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Born"
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Position"
            With .Columns(4)
                .HeaderCell.Value = "Salary"
                .HeaderCell.Style = rightStyle
                .DefaultCellStyle = curStyle
            End With
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Name"
        End With
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I removed the c# tag. This question had nothing to do with c#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a space between the last selected column and `FROM`. Right now, you query ends up as:

```
SELECT ..., teammates.SalaryFROM
```

Notice the lack of a space. So just add a space to the start of the next string:

```
sql += " From teammates INNER
'       ^ notice the space
```

Which will result in:

```
SELECT ..., teammates.Salary FROM
--                          ^^ space
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it one string, like this:

```
sql = "SELECT teammates.PlayerName, teammates.Number, teammates.BirthDate, Position.Position, teammates.Salary From teammates INNER JOIN Position ON teammates.PositionID = Position.PositionID"
```